# pands return '/' instead of ',' when aggregating a column

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know what I did wrong to get '/' as a separator instead of ','

```py
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

#get indexes of row that contains a not assigned borough
indexNames = df[ df['Borough'] == 'Not assigned' ].index

# Delete these row indexes from dataFrame
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
df.groupby('Postal code').agg({'Borough' : 'first', 'Neighborhood' : ','.join}).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

[image]

Comment: That's in the HTML: `<td>Malvern / Rouge
</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong, postal code is a unique column so it doesn't group by. The '/' was already there, if you want to replace it by ',' you can do it like this:

```
df['Neighborhood'] = df['Neighborhood'].str.replace('/', ',')
```